# Oracle Query with two 'HAVING' conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, having

I have a query and i want to have two `HAVING` conditions

- The first condition is where sum is more than 6000 (Which i have
  done)
- The second condition is where the COUNT(1) CNT is more than 1 (Which
  i need help in)

  ```
  SELECT SYSDATE,
         CUSTOMER.CIF_NO,
         CUSTOMER.LONG_NAME_ENG,
         TRANSTYPE.short_desc_Eng,
         LOCATION.LONG_DESC_ENG ,
         COUNT(1) CNT,
         SUM(TRANS.AMOUNT) SM
    FROM TRANS, CUSTOMER, TRANSTYPE, LOCATION
   WHERE TRANS.TRS_AC_CIF = CUSTOMER.CIF_NO
     AND TRANS.BRANCH_CODE = LOCATION.BRANCH_CODE
     AND TRANS.COMP_CODE = LOCATION.COMP_CODE
     AND TRANSTYPE.COMP_CODE = TRANS.COMP_CODE
     AND TRANSTYPE.TYPE IN ( 'D' ,  'T' )
     AND TRANSTYPE.CODE = TRANS.TRX_TYPE
     AND TRANS.STATUS = 'P'
     AND TRANS.TRS_TYPE = 'R'
     AND TRANS.CB_IND = 'C'
   GROUP BY CUSTOMER.CIF_NO ,CUSTOMER.LONG_NAME_ENG, 
            TRANSTYPE.short_desc_Eng,  LOCATION.LONG_DESC_ENG 
  HAVING SUM(TRANS.AMOUNT) > 6000 
  ---------------------------
  second having here 
  ----------------------------
   ORDER BY CUSTOMER.CIF_NO, CUSTOMER.LONG_NAME_ENG, LOCATION.LONG_DESC_ENG
  ```

Answer (score 3):

More than one `HAVING` clause can not be specified within a SELECT statement, e.g. it's a violation. But add your needed condition such as

```
HAVING SUM(TRANS.AMOUNT) > 6000 AND COUNT(1) > 1
```

**OR**

```
HAVING SUM(TRANS.AMOUNT) > 6000 OR COUNT(1) > 1
```

as long as

- a GROUP BY clause is present with the SQL statement
- aggregations take place within the HAVING clause

*P.S. Convert your query syntax to the syntax with **explicit JOIN** clauses among tables rather than old-style comma-seperated JOINs, and use **aliases** for the table names*